# Convergence in probability 3

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

For a given $ε>0$ we have the assumption that

$$
Z(ε):=\begin{cases}
Z, & \text{if }\Vert Z \Vert < \dfrac{1}{ε}\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

We want to show that 
$$Z(ε) \xrightarrow{P} Z.$$

***Idea of the solution:***

we have to show that 
For  $δ>0$

$$P \left\lbrace \vert Z(ε) -Z \vert > δ \right\rbrace  = 0 \quad \text{as } ε \rightarrow 0.$$

Or equivalently,$$
P \left\lbrace  \Vert Z \Vert > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right\rbrace  =0\quad \text{as } ε \rightarrow 0.
$$

I could not get the full idea of the solution. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Best regards,

Mohammad

Answer (score -1):

By dominated convergence theorem,$$
\lim_{ε \to 0^+} P\left( \|Z\| > \frac{1}{ε} \right) = \lim_{ε \to 0^+} E\left( I_{\{\|z\| > \frac{1}{ε}\}}(Z) \right) = E\left( \lim_{ε \to 0^+} I_{\{\|z\| > \frac{1}{ε}\}}(Z) \right) = 0.
$$

Comment: The sets $\{||Z||>\frac 1 {\epsilon}\}$ decrease to the empty set as $\epsilon \to 0+$ so you don't really need DCT for this.

Comment: Just to make the quesion more clear: $Z(epsilon) $ is a cutting-off from the original vector Z and  we have based the first assumption   $Z(\epsilon) -Z \vert= \begin{cases}
0, \ if \quad \Vert Z \Vert < \frac{1}{\epsilon}\\
-Z, \ if \quad \Vert Z \Vert > \frac{1}{\epsilon}.
\end{cases}          $